# Using "to" before adverbs of place

Tags: adverbs, to-infinitive

I'm interested in whether we can use "to" before "here" and "there".

- You can always return to here whenever you want.
- You should never go to there.

Is it idiomatic in any way? Does it have a valid grammatical usage?

Comment: That's not idiomatic in standard contemporary English but it was used in prior centuries and still has some currency in regional dialects. Have you seen it that way somewhere?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo My penpal from africa wrote "If you go over to there..." so I thought it might be possible in their dialect. Probably it is simply bad English.

Comment: Yes, because that implies: if you go **over** to [some place]. But that is not: go to there. "If you go over to there [a place], you will see that."

Comment: Such usage is only limited to specific expressions like 'from here to there' which would be unclear without 'to'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because in standard English "to" introduces a predicate or prepositional phrase.

- I love to play tennis.
- I love going to the movies.

Go here/go there. I really don't think regional dialects really matter at this level. I have never seen it and just because it might exist in some odd little area is just not relevant as a general principle. Maybe it does exist in the Outer Hebrides, but is that relevant here? Thousands of variations exist to just about everything.

- Please do **go to the party** this evening. Please **do go there" this evening.